# Sum in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I have a recursive function which I call `acc`. If a specific condition is fulfilled I call the function again. If not, I want do add a number to the variable `a`.

In my opinion it does not what it should. Can someone have a look on this:

```
double acc(v)
{
    double a = 0;
    for(int q=0; q<v; q++)
    {
            if(bf(q) < 1)
            {
                if(ef() == 0)
                {           
                    a += cf();
                }
                else
                {
                    a += df();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return a += acc(v);
            }
    }   
    return a;
}
```

I tried to simplify it as good as I can. `v`is a variable. `bf()`, `cf()`, `ef()` and `df()` are functions which return an integer value. Now I want that `a` gets incremented every time a specific condition is fulfilled during the whole recursive process. Does my code what I want? I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: What is `Leaf`?

Comment: What do you mean "does my code what I want"? How can we know, test it debug it etc.

Comment: We can have no idea what it does, or should do. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output. Does your opinion extend to hard facts?

Comment: what do you want? This function may produce a stackoverflow because the recursive call ` return a += acc(v);` is performed with the exact same argument.

Comment: Why do you use `double` if all the functions return `int`? is `Leaf` a `double` too, and comparing floating point value causes your problems? We can only speculate.

Comment: UmNyobe is right. If `bf(0) < 1` is false, then you do `a += acc(v);`. If `bf(0) < 1` is still false, then you do `a += acc(v);` again. This continues until you've overflowed your stack or until `bf(0) < 1` is true. Hopefully `cf()` and `df()` don't call `acc(v)`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats also a function. I corrected it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
The code you posted does not reproduce the problem, and you've failed to specify the problem.

Comment: @Samuel so it is not even your code. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Note that `double acc(v)` is an K&R-style (non-prototype) function definition — and a sloppy one at that since it could be `double acc(v) int v; { … }` to be explicit about the type of `v`.  Such code should not be written by anyone these days.  It is extremely poor form.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a is defined inside the recursive function. If you want to count events inside the recursion, declare a outside of acc().

Comment: The result of the recursive call is added to `a` and returned.  `a` may also be incremented by the results of `cf()` and `df()`.  There is no need to make `a` global to make recursion work.